# Creating Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, vba

My code consists of two components:

1. A sheet that copies a table from another workbook
2. A sheet that requires a pivot table be generated using data from the copied table.

My code to copy the table from another Excel file (located in same folder) to the active workbook. (This code works.):

```
Sub Copy_YTD()

Dim wsCopy as Worksheet

Dim wsDest as Worksheet

Dim CopyLastRow As Long

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\....."

Set wsCopy = Workbooks("QA_Allocations_YTD.xlsm").Worksheets("YTD")

Set wsDest = Workbooks("YTD_Report_Generator.xlsm").Worksheets("YTD")

CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

wsCopy.Range("A1:AZ" & CopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A4")

Workbooks("QA_Allocations_YTD.xlsm").Close

End Sub
```

Below is the code to create a Pivot table in an existing sheet.

When I try to run it from the sheet, this generates

> "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

AND

> Error code "400"

```
Sub Create_Pivot_Table()

Dim destws As Worksheet

Dim wb As Workbook 

Dim pc As PivotCache

Dim pt As PivotTable

Set destws = Worksheets("Funding Type Breakdown")
Set wb = ThisWorkbook 

'below Range("QA_Allocations_YTD") is ALWAYS the table name which is copied,
' I also tried Range(Sheets("YTD").Range("QA_Allocations_YTD")) but to no success

Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Range("QA_Allocations_YTD"))

Set pt = destws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pc, TableDestination:=Range("E10"), TableName:="P1")

End Sub
```

I tried different methods; this one being the simplest and I run into the same error message.

Comment: `Range("QA_Allocations_YTD")` probably best to qualify this with a specific worksheet object.  Same for the `Range("E10")` in the next line.  Unqualified `Range()` calls always (in a regular code module) default to `ActiveSheet`, which is often not the sheet you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Create_Pivot_Table()

    Dim destws As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet

    Dim wb As Workbook 

    Dim pc As PivotCache

    Dim pt As PivotTable

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
    Set destws = wb.Worksheets("Funding Type Breakdown")
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("YTD")

    Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                SourceData:=wsData.Range("QA_Allocations_YTD"))

    Set pt = destws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pc, _
                TableDestination:=destws.Range("E10"), TableName:="P1")

End Sub
```